# Periodically update data in Sql Azure Database

Tags: sql, azure

I have an SQL Azure Database instance which provide data to a windows 8 app. The data in my database should be updated periodically (weekly). Is the any way to make it? I'm thinking of write a app which will run weekly and update the database. But still don't know how to make it run on Window Azure? Please help!
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, does the data however need to come from a different source or can it be calculated?

Either way, seeing as you're already knee deep in SQL Azure I would suggest putting your logic into a [worker role](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/windows-azure-web-worker-and-vm-roles-demystified/4017) that can be scheduled to run your updates once a week. This would give you a great opportunity to do calculations and/or fetch data externally.

Azure gives you the flexibility to scale this worker role into numerous instances as well depending on the work load.

Here is a nice intro tutorial on creating a worker role on Azure: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50411/Simple-6-Steps-to-Run-your-First-Azure-Worker-Role)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I understand now and following your link.

Answer (score 0):

Write the application and set it to run through your cron job manager on a weekly time schedule. The cron job manager should be provided by your host.